# PHP I/O memory stream create empty line at the beginning of document

Tags: php, memory, stream

I'm new in php and I have question on you.
For now, I'm creating one php script where I want use this:

```
$file = fopen('php://memory','w');
```

Then, I use fputcsv where I add few arrays to fill into this document.
In the final part, I said that I want make downloadeble link

```
header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="service.csv"');
```

My method look like this:

```
public function exportToCsv($Id){
  $file = fopen('php://memory','w');

  $someDetails = $this->some_model->getSomeDetail($Id);

  $details = array(
    array("Subject", "Start Date", "Start Time", "End Date", "End Time", "Where"),
    array("test subject","test date","test time","test end date","etc..."));
  foreach ($details as $detail) {
      fputcsv($file, $detail);
  }
  fseek($file,0);
  header('Content-Type: application/csv');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.csv"');
  fpassthru($file);}
```

When my browser download this file and when I open it, everything is great, but at the beginning of file, there is one empty line and I dont understand why it happend and how can I remove this line.

Thanks for describe.

Marek

Comment: Do you have any blank space / blank line before or after the php tag ? (<?php   ?> )

Comment: No, I used CodeIgniter framework and this code was write in controller. Blank line/space was not found. When I open created document, the first line is blank and others lines are filled.

And I forgot mention .. all this happend only when I use path "php://memory" or output,...
When I write path like "C:/path/to/folder" everything is fine, no blank line is created ... only "php://memory" create blank line at the beginning

Comment: Try adding  ob_end_clean();   just before your fpassthru($file);

Comment: What an excellent advice! It works! I want kiss you :D thanks

Comment: No problem, glad it worked ! I'll rewrite my comment as an answer so you can accept it:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 ) You should check if there is any blank line / space before the PHP Tags ( `<?php  ?>` )

2) Try adding `ob_end_clean();` just before your `fpassthru($file);` , this will clear the buffer and you'll be sure there's nothing left in it.